# how to use polling function and Jump out early if another condition is met in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a polling function to check the value of get status_code variable for 60 seconds.

```
import requests
try:
    polling.poll(
        lambda: requests.get('http://google.com').status_code == 200, step=1, timeout=60)
except polling.TimeoutException, te:
    while not te.values.empty():
        print te.values.get()
```

but if response.status_code=400, No need to wait for timeout to jump out of polling in advance，jump out of polling immediately,what should i do?

Comment: Not use lambda and move the request to a function `check_status_code`.